# javascript filter elements not found in second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, filter

*solved: requires explicit return statement for each filter. I thought the single boolean in each filter would be clear enough.* by @adiga

**I want to find the elements in one array (dcm) that are not found in a second array (vari).** I want to match only two elements, vp (string type) and vd (date type). I've made sure there are some rows in dcm that meet the condition, but I'm **getting no results**.

Did I do up the code wrong? is there a better way to do this (.includes .contains .indexOf)?

```
  var dcmm = dcm.filter(r=>{
    vari.filter(rv=>{
      rv[vp]+rv[vd] == r[dp]+r[dd]
      }).length == 0
    });
```

ps. sorrynotsorry to all the long variable name proponents out there. as well as the const-not-var proponents.
pps. this is google apps script not javascript, but I think the idea is the same.

Comment: You are not returning from either `filter` callback. Please add some data for those variables. It's not clear what you're asking

Comment: each filter has only one argument, so I thought the return was assumed. vari.filter returns all the elements for which those two elements are true. then the dcm filter returns all the elements where that return from vari was length 0 (ie not found). Should I just write 'return' prior to each one of those two boolean expressions?

Comment: actually I think that did it. I thought the return was optional if there was only one expressions. I guess it doesn't count as a single expression like that...

Comment: You could omit the braces on the arrow functions for implicit return.

Comment: arrow functions have implicit return when you don't have `{}` wrapper around the functions. Please create a [mcve] with some sample data and good variables names. Just because you are using these short variables for whatever reason, doesn't mean you can't have descriptive names when posting here. You need to make it easy for us help you. There are probably better ways to do this. `rv[vp]+rv[vd] == r[dp]+r[dd]` looks like a bad way to compare 2 properties

Comment: I gave you variable types. what does it matter what the variable names or data are if you know data types? it's all fixed now though. you did answer the question instantly, so it must not have been that vague. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case, as it said @adiga you don't need `return` statements if you don't use `{}`.

Most likely this will work fine:

```
var dcmm = dcm.filter( r => vari.filter( rv => (rv[vp]+rv[vd] == r[dp]+r[dd]) ).length == 0 );
```

Comment: I added those {} at the end. I guess the issue was that I overthought it not that I under-thought it...

Comment: @JasonTorpy you can probably short-circuit the inner filter by changing it to `every` or `some` : `dcm.filter(r => vari.every(rv => rv[vp] !== r[dp] && rv[vd] !== r[dd]) )`. filter will go through every item in the vari array.`every` will stop going further if the condition fails for an array element